# HP computer stuck at bootup screen for no apparent reason

Tags: boot, desktop-computer

I don't recall having done anything to my computer, but I rebooted out of an Ubuntu Live CD in the hope of getting to Windows. Instead, the computer hangs at the HP Invent bootup screen. Hitting Esc to enter the boot menu causes it to display "Loading Boot Menu" and stop there; other buttons do nothing. (UPDATE 2013/6/21: It turns out that it hangs for about an hour, and isn't permanent.

What I have tried:

- Unplugging everything and plugging it back in
- Removing and resetting the RAM
- Replacing the CMOS battery
- Removing the hard drives I use, thus destroying my RAID and the data

Any help?

Comment: Specs/Model of computer? To clarify, the "Loading Boot Menu" you mention is from the BIOS right? **Before** the Windows Boot screen? To be honest, I've seen this behavior several dozen times, each time it's because the HDD is going bad and this prevents booting and in rare occasions BIOS access (like you describe). Sorry dude but ur gunna have to try booting without the drives for a full diagnosis, in my opinion/experience.

Comment: Can't say too much for specs because I don't really know that much about it. It's a Pavilion desktop old enough to run Vista, but two of the three hard drives are new. I suppose I'll try it tomorrow........it's backed up....

Comment: Yea I thought as much, I'm pretty sure I know the kind of screen it's stalling on. I'm not at all familiar with a "fake RAID" but surely taking out **all** the drives before boot, just to see if you can make it past the splash screen, won't ruin the RAID?

Comment: Apparently I can get past the splash screen if I wait for about an hour. It booted into Vista this time (meaning my RAID isn't the problem), but it doesn't see the third hard drive that isn't part of the RAID. What I remember doing was using the Ubuntu Live CD to dd my backup .img (stored on a USB external drive) to that third hard drive, but that can't possibly have broken the entire disk...right?

Comment: Well yes and no. To clarify I don't think you're RAID is the issue so much as the actual HDD's. They can absolutely go bad and when they do, you get issues like waiting an hour to boot... as for the dd command, depending on what command you ran, it could make the drive unseeable in Win OS. You've got to run some HDD diagnostics on your drive especially if theyre in RAID. Over and out.

Comment: HP diagnostics wouldn't load because of the screen hanging. Vista started giving me errors for everything, including the Data Collector diagnostics thingy timing out. I pulled all three of my hard drives out sequentially (destroying my RAID), and it didn't fix anything.